# can not update the value in pandas dataframe using .loc inside the circle

Tags: python, pandas

I try to update values in pandas DataFrame (column №9) using a 'for':

```
k=1 
for index, row in stations.iterrows():
if np.isnan(row.label):   
    p1 = Polygon([(row.long, row.lat),(row.long1, row.lat1),(row.long2, row.lat2)])
    stations.iloc[index, 9] = k
    for index1, row1 in stations[(index+1):min((index+10), len(stations))].iterrows():
        p2 = Polygon([(row1.long, row1.lat),(row1.long1, row1.lat1),(row1.long2, row1.lat2)]) 
        if p1.intersects(p2):
            stations.iloc[index1, 9] = k
    k = k + 1
```

But when I see on the result DataFrame stations, I see that it isn't changed by the second circle...
Could you help me?

So, the example of data:

[image]

Comment: You need to provide at least a sample data so that I can understand what the problem is.

Comment: you missed an indent in the third and consecutive lines. For setting values `.at` is advised

Comment: Thanks!!! You are right!